# How do I find the tables and columns which make up a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view in one of our DBs and I need to find out where the values in the view come from

How do I go about this? (SQL Server Management Studio)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sp_helptext viewname
```

This will give you the view text and from there you can know the tables and it's columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views WHERE TABLE_NAME='view_Name'
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Object Explorer, find the view you're interested in, right-click on it, and pick

```
Script View As > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window
```

The SQL script that defines the view and thus also shows all the base tables it depends on will be scripted out into a new query editor window for you.

[image]

Or in Management Studio, you can also use the `sp_depends` system stored procedure to get all the dependencies for your object:

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'HumanResources.vJobCandidate'
```

gives you an output of:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get hold of a View Columns

1. View columns list and their datatype etc

```
SELECT
   [c].*
FROM
   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] [c]
      INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] [t] ON [c].[TABLE_CATALOG] = [t].[TABLE_CATALOG] AND [c].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = [t].[TABLE_SCHEMA] AND [c].[TABLE_NAME] = [t].[TABLE_NAME]
WHERE
   [t].[TABLE_TYPE] = 'VIEW'
```

2. The View definition itself, can inspect the db native code

Use the system proc: `sp_helptext 'my_schema.vw_view_name'`
Via a query:

```
SELECT
   [v].[TABLE_SCHEMA]
   , [v].[TABLE_NAME]
   , [v].[VIEW_DEFINITION]
FROM
   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[views] [v]
```

3. View columns and their base tables, note NOT all view columns will appear here. MSSQL only returns columns that tend to have direct mapping to a base table, for example no alias names. Also, it's possible to base views on views and thus the whole tree may need traversing, depending on needs.

```
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE]
```

A more informative query here, that returns ALL view columns. The column `BASED_ON_TABLE_IS_KNOWN` is a flag that denotes whether the view column's base table/view column was found.

```
SELECT
   IIF([cu].[VIEW_NAME] IS NULL ,'N' ,'Y') [BASED_ON_TABLE_IS_KNOWN]
   , [c].[TABLE_CATALOG] [VIEW_CATALOG]
   , [c].[TABLE_SCHEMA] [VIEW_SCHEMA]
   , [c].[TABLE_NAME] [VIEW_NAME]
   , [c].[COLUMN_NAME] [VIEW_COLUMN_NAME]
   , [cu].[TABLE_NAME] [BASED_ON_TABLE_NAME]
   , [cu].[TABLE_SCHEMA] [BASED_ON_TABLE_SCHEMA]
   , [cu].[TABLE_CATALOG] [BASED_ON_TABLE_CATALOG]
   , [cu].[COLUMN_NAME] [BASED_ON_COLUMN_NAME]
   , c.[DATA_TYPE]

FROM
   ( [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] [c] INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] [t]
     ON [c].[TABLE_CATALOG] = [t].[TABLE_CATALOG] AND [c].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = [t].[TABLE_SCHEMA] AND [c].[TABLE_NAME] = [t].[TABLE_NAME] )
      LEFT OUTER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE] [cu]
                      ON [c].[COLUMN_NAME] = [cu].[COLUMN_NAME] AND [cu].[VIEW_CATALOG] = [t].[TABLE_CATALOG] AND [cu].[VIEW_SCHEMA] = [t].[TABLE_SCHEMA] AND [cu].[VIEW_NAME] = [t].[TABLE_NAME]

WHERE
   [t].[TABLE_TYPE] = 'VIEW'
   AND [t].[TABLE_NAME] = 'vw_invoice_main'
   AND [t].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dev_test_example_2'
```

5. Table/Views that a referenced by a View

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

6. Use the MSSQL system object views and tables, these contain rich information. Below are some useful queries

```
-- get all the entities referenced by a view
select distinct schema_name(v.schema_id) as view_schema_name,
       v.name as view_name,
       schema_name(o.schema_id) as referenced_schema_name,
       o.name as referenced_entity_name,
       o.type_desc as referenced_entity_type
from sys.views v
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
     on d.referencing_id = v.object_id
     and d.referenced_id is not null
join sys.objects o
     on o.object_id = d.referenced_id
 order by view_schema_name,
          view_name;
```